# mypy fails to narrow down generic types in `TypeGuard`-based conditionals

Tags: python, types, mypy, typing, type-narrowing

Trying to create a type-pure container in Python, I've stumbled upon type-narrowing failure of generic types by mypy when creating a signature of the `__setitem__` method.

Before we dive in, I'm using:

- mypy 0.991
- python 3.10.6.

---

First, let's consider a basic example.

Let us define two types, `A` and `B`, and a type variable `AB` that can be either `A` or `B` (but not a `Union[A, B]`):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t
from collections import abc
from itertools import tee
from typing_extensions import reveal_type


class A:
    ...
    

class B:
    ...

AB = t.TypeVar('AB', A, B)  # Strictly A or B
```

Now, suppose we want to define a function or method with the following signature:

```py
def fn(arg: AB | abc.Iterable[AB]):
```

The function's body will depend on whether `AB` or `abc.Iterable[AB]` are provided.
To check that, let's introduce the following utilities:

```py
T = t.TypeVar('T')


def is_iterable_of(
        s: abc.Iterable[t.Any], _type: t.Type[T]
) -> t.TypeGuard[abc.Iterable[T]]:
    return all(isinstance(x, _type) for x in s)


def is_type(x: t.Any, _type: t.Type[T]) -> t.TypeGuard[T]:
    return isinstance(x, _type)


def is_a_or_b(x: t.Any) -> t.TypeGuard[A | B]:
    return isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B)


def is_iterable_of_ab(s: abc.Iterable[t.Any]) -> t.TypeGuard[abc.Iterable[AB]]:
    ss = tee(s)
    
    return any(
            is_iterable_of(_s, _t) for _s, _t in zip(ss, [A, B])
        )
```

I think only `is_iterable_of_ab` might be a little confusing: it checks whether the provided iterable contains all `A` types or all `B` types. To view what `TypeGuard` types are doing, please refer to the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html#user-defined-type-guards).

We apply our type-narrowing functions in `fn` as follows:

```py
def fn(arg: A | B | abc.Iterable[AB]):
    if is_a_or_b(arg):
        # Process single instance
        reveal_type(arg)  # A | B
    else:
        # Process multiple instances
        reveal_type(arg)  # (A | B | Iterable[A]) | (A | B | Iterable[B])
        assert is_iterable_of_ab(arg)
```

Mypy produces the following output (you can check the full example's code in [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ba923013c1ad4c6bf877cd16ee4974da)):

```
main.py:46: note: Revealed type is "Union[__main__.A, __main__.B]"
main.py:49: note: Revealed type is "Union[__main__.A, __main__.B, typing.Iterable[__main__.A]]"
main.py:49: note: Revealed type is "Union[__main__.A, __main__.B, typing.Iterable[__main__.B]]"
main.py:50: error: Argument 1 to "is_iterable_of_ab" has incompatible type "Union[A, B, Iterable[A]]"; expected "Iterable[Any]"  [arg-type]
main.py:50: error: Argument 1 to "is_iterable_of_ab" has incompatible type "Union[A, B, Iterable[B]]"; expected "Iterable[Any]"  [arg-type]
```

What is confusing here is that the call to `is_a_or_b`, while narrows down the type to `A | B` correctly, doesn't lead to mypy recognizing that if the conditional is `False`, the provided `arg` must have the `abc.Iterable[AB]` type. As a result, any functionality inside the `else` block that depends on `arg` being `Iterable[AB]` will raise an error since mypy thinks `arg` is can still be `A | B`.

Note that this also fails:

```py
def fn2(arg: A | B | abc.Iterable[AB]):
    if is_a_or_b(arg):
        # Process single instance
        reveal_type(arg)  # A | B
    elif is_iterable_of_ab(arg):  # error: incompatible type
        # Process multiple instances
        reveal_type(arg)  # wrong type: Iterable[A]
    else:
        raise TypeError()
```

**So, how could I correctly use type-narrowing here?**

---

For a more realistic example indicated at the beginning, consider making a type pure list class:

```py
class TypePureList(t.Generic[AB]):
    
    def __init__(self, items: abc.Iterable[AB]):
        if not isinstance(items, list):
            items = list(items)
        self._items: list[AB] = items
    
    @t.overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: t.SupportsIndex, value: AB):
        ...
    
    @t.overload
    def __setitem__(self, index: slice, value: abc.Iterable[AB]):
        ...
    
    def __setitem__(self, index: t.SupportsIndex | slice, value: AB | abc.Iterable[AB]):
        
        if len(self._items) == 0:
            raise ValueError
        
        if isinstance(index, t.SupportsIndex):
            # Check that the value type is correct by itself
            assert is_a_or_b(value)
            # Check that the value type matches the existing type
            assert is_iterable_of_ab([self._items[0], value])
            reveal_type(value)  # A | B
        else:
            # Index must be slice
            # Value must be Iterable
            reveal_type(index)  # slice
            reveal_type(value)  # (A | Iterable[A]) | (B | Iterable[B])
            # Check that the iterable contains correct types
            value, value1, value2 = tee(value, 3)  # error: incompatible type
            assert is_iterable_of_ab(value1)
            # Check if the iterable types match the existing type
            assert is_iterable_of_ab([self._items[0], next(value2)])

        # error: invalid syntax -- index is Union[SupportsIndex, slice]
        # error: incompatible types in assignment
        self._items.__setitem__(index, value)
```

Firstly, mypy fails to use the overloading information, but that seems to be an ongoing issue (see [#7858](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7858)).
Secondly, same as above, mypy fails to narrow down the types following the assertion that if index has `SupportsIndex` type, then `value` must be `Iterable[AB]` due to `assert is_a_or_b(value)`.

---

Comment: *...What is confusing here is that the call to is_a_or_b, while narrows down the type to A | B correctly, doesn't lead to mypy recognizing that if the conditional is False, the provided arg must have the abc.Iterable[AB] type...* This is wrong. This is really not explained in docs (if you feel like - please submit a doc PR), but `TypeGuard` narrows only by `True`. If it returns `False`, no additional assumptions are made (e.g. you can have `my_tg(x: object) -> TypeGuard[float]` that returns `False` for `x = 1` - but cannot have it return `True` for `x = 'foo'`)

Comment: What about something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=45cf9490c0ab74c8be9232da1fbbdbe9)?